# Algorithm for reducing GPS track data to discard redundant data?

Tags: gps, gis, geospatial, openlayers

We're building a GIS interface to display GPS track data, e.g. imagine the raw data set from a guy wandering around a neighborhood on a bike for an hour.  A set of data like this with perhaps a new point recorded every 5 seconds, will be large and displaying it in a browser or a handheld device will be challenging.  Also, displaying every single point is usually not necessary since a user can't visually resolve that much data anyway.

So for performance reasons we are looking for algorithms that are good at 'reducing' data like this so that the number of points being displayed is reduced significantly but in such a way that it doesn't risk data mis-interpretation.  For example, if our fictional bike rider stops for a drink, we certainly don't want to draw 100 lat/lon points in a cluster around the 7-Eleven.

We are aware of clustering, which is good for when looking at a bunch of disconnected points, however what we need is something that applies to **tracks** as described above.  Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at the source of gpsbabel's [simplify](http://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-1.3.5/filter_simplify.html) option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the best way of doing that is:

1. Determine the minimum number of screen pixels you want between GPS points displayed.
2. Determine the distance represented by each pixel in the current zoom level.
3. Multiply answer 1 by answer 2 to get the minimum distance between coordinates you want to display.
4. starting from the first coordinate in the journey path, read each next coordinate until you've reached the required minimum distance from the current point. Repeat.

Comment: THanks, but perhaps I should've used a better example than a bicycle rider: a salesman working a neighborhood on foot might be better because the data we're dealing with could involve circling back and various other somewhat random motion as opposed to a the oversimplification of someone going on a trip, where each point is farther from the origin than the last.

Comment: Actually, the algorithm in my answer still holds. If points are not beyond the minimum travel, they're not shown unless the zoom level is increased.

Comment: Yeah, that might work.  Also now seeing mentions of Kalman filtering however that's an advanced solution that is harder to implement and could have processing / performance problems.  Thanks again

Answer (score 8):

A more scientific and perhaps more math heavy solution is to use the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) to generalize your path. I used it when I studied for my Master of Surveying so it's a proven thing. :-)

Giving your path and the minimum angle you can tolerate in your path, it simplifies the path by reducing the number of points.

[image: From the Wikipedia article]

Comment: Thanks. This is the type of thing I'm looking for and will have to find out how cpu-intensive it is and whether I can find or write an implementation for our server.

Comment: Cool! Best of luck to you. But you chose the other answer as the solution, will you try that first?

Comment: Not sure.  Having given this more thought, 'real' gps data with people driving around tends to generate crazy loops and clusters of noise and circles and such.  This algorithm while very cool appears to be better for data where you can discern the start point and the end point.  Have to give it more thought.  Plus the processing could involve a square of the number of points so it might have performance limitations.

Comment: Yeah, I think some sort of initial filtering is good too. Based on a minimum distance between the points or something like that. But I disagree on the usability of the algorithm though - I think it would suffice well, with the addition of using lines (perhaps arrows) between the points. But that would be necessary for every method showing "crazy loops" :-)